# Get specific values from array and convert the values to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array like below

```
[{
"title": "Apple iPhone 7 Plus 32 GB",
"category": "phone",
"brand": "apple",
"condition": "Used",
"price": 800,
"id": 0,
"description": "Apple"
}, {
    "title": "Apple Ipad Air 32 GB",
    "category": "tablet",

    "brand": "apple",
    "condition": "new",
    "price": 1000,
    "id": 1,
    "description": "Apple"
},{
    "title": "Supreme Box Logo Hooded Sweatshirt Navy",
    "category": "clothes",
    "brand": "Supreme",
    "condition": "new",
    "price": 1000,
    "id": 2,
    "description": "Supreme Size M"
},]
```

How can I get only values of category from above array and convert them to array like this?

```
[{"phone","clothes","tablet"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just map through your array and grab the `category` of each.

Also `[{"phone","clothes","tablet"}]` isn't valid; an object is pairs of keys and values, so I'm assuming you meant `["phone","clothes","tablet"]`

```js
const items = [{
"title": "Apple iPhone 7 Plus 32 GB",
"category": "phone",
"brand": "apple",
"condition": "Used",
"price": 800,
"id": 0,
"description": "Apple"
}, {
    "title": "Apple Ipad Air 32 GB",
    "category": "tablet",

    "brand": "apple",
    "condition": "new",
    "price": 1000,
    "id": 1,
    "description": "Apple"
},{
    "title": "Supreme Box Logo Hooded Sweatshirt Navy",
    "category": "clothes",
    "brand": "Supreme",
    "condition": "new",
    "price": 1000,
    "id": 2,
    "description": "Supreme Size M"
},];

const newItems = items.map(item => item.category);
console.log(newItems)
```

Comment: @Genuineeek if larz's answer is correct please mark it a such. Also, this isn't a ReactJS question, it's just a plain Javascript question. Make sure to tag questions correctly, it will help maximise your chances of getting an answer and help others find it.